# imap_open get last UNSEEN e-mail

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm working on a php script, that need to open my G-mail account find the oldest UNSEEN e-mail. When it find the oldest e-mail it has to flag the e-mail as SEEN, and check if the e-mail has any attached file.

I open my G-mail with this:

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to E-mail: ' .     imap_last_error());
```

Hope anyone can help my.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty minimal attempt.  Have you looked into imap_search, imap_fetch, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for the `imap_status` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-status.php

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to E-mail: ' .     imap_last_error());
$status = imap_status($inbox, $hostname."INBOX", SA_ALL);

 if ($status) {
  echo "Unseen:     " . $status->unseen      . "<br />\n";
 }
```